# Gummi Not Using TexLive 2012

Tags: installing, texlive

I use Gummi was LaTeX document editing.

I recently installed TeX Live 2012 as per instructions [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).
Also I previously had TeX Live installed from Ubuntu Software Center which I uninstalled.

Now, when I start Gummi and load some old LaTeX documents, it seems Gummi doesn't know anything about new TeX Live 2012 installation and uses old TeX program (I don't understand where it loads this old program from since I uninstalled TeX Live from Software Center).

This is the first line in Gummi's build log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
```

Does it come with its own `TeX Live`? How do I make it use `TeX Live 2012`?

In fact when I type in command `pdflatex` in the terminal, I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
```

where as when I `cd /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux` and type in `./pdflatex`, I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

I had properly exported `PATH` variable after installing `TeX Live 2012` by adding following entry in my `~/.pam_environment` file:

```
PATH            DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux
```

When I `echo $PATH` above directory can be seen added to `PATH`.

Looks like some old TeX Live program is taking preference over TeX Live 2012.

Comment: Did you add TeX Live 2012 to your path?

Comment: @JosephWright: I just edited my question. I have added details regarding exporting location of `Tex Live 2012` in `PATH` variable.

Comment: You have added TeX Live to the end  of your path, so the managed one will come first. What happens if you have `DEFAULT=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:${PATH}`?

Comment: @JosephWright: I added the `TeX Live 2012` directory in front to the PATH and now Gummi uses 2012 installation. However, where did it find `TeX Live 2009` installation when I had it uninstalled from software center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must change the order in the PATH-variable:
Instead of

```
PATH            DEFAULT=${PATH}:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux
```

It should be

```
PATH            DEFAULT=/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux:${PATH}
```

Because the Operating system uses the first command it finds in the PATH, it will use the latex/pdflatex which are installed by Debian, and not of your installation.

Out of topic: You can use "which latex" to find which comand is used. (Type it in the shell.)

Comment: If I switch the paths, system uses `TeX Live 2012`. However using command `which latex` I found out that otherwise system uses `latex` in `/usr/bin/latex`. When I try to remove this using `apt-get remove` command I get `Virtual packages like 'latex' can't be removed`. What is the meaning of this message? And how can I remove `latex`?

Comment: Virtual package is a generic name that applies to any one of a group of packages, all of which provide similar basic functionality. ([link]http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html) You can remove the latex installation from debian by removing the package `texlive-base`, `texlive-binaries`, an so on. But you should'n because apt-get will remove other packages, which need tex.